# Finding a Real valued Function to Create Holomorphism

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I am asked whether it is possible to find a real function $v$ such that $$x^3+y^3+iv$$ is holomorphic.

Should I basically be working backwards from the Cauchy-Riemann equations? That makes logical sense to me, but I don't really see how it would come together exactly.

Thanks

Comment: you will get a partial differential equation on $u$, probably solve it using elimination and integrate like you did with gradient in multivariable calc.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^3 + y^3 + iv$ were holomorphic, then the real part $u(x, y) = x^3 + y^3$ would be harmonic, that is, $u$ would satisfy $\nabla^2 u = 0$.  But $\nabla^2 u = 6(x + y) \ne 0$, so $u$ is not harmonic, so $u + iv = x^3 + y^3 + iv$ cannot be holomorphic for any $v$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: I'm not sure that this is quite right, since we can break down the laplace operator too $\Delta =(\partial_x-i\partial_ y)(\partial_x+i\partial_y)$

Comment: @ellya:  if I am not mistaken, the real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are indeed harmonic; this follows from CR; so, if $x^3 + y^3 + iv$ is holomorphic . . . What exactly are you suggesting?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it changes things, but for complex functions, the imaginary part influences whether it would be holomorphic, by rewriting it as I have.

Comment: @ellya:  harmonic conjugates.  $u + iv$ holomophic imply $u, v$ as a pair are yoked together *via* CR, but each must satisfy $\nabla^2 u = \nabla^2 v = 0$ on its own.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, +1